# Extracting time in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have character field in the following format

df

```
sd
10/12/2017 6:12
10/12/2017 6:14
```

I want to convert it into date format so that I can extract time from it.

Now having read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707383/extract-time-from-timestamp), I don't want to use regex as I want to keep it more generic as the formats might change. So I wanted to convert it to a date format and use lubridate to extract required fields.

So i used the following :

```
d1 <- strptime(df$sd[1], "%m/%d/%Y%H:%M")
```

and it gives me the following result

```
d1
[1] "2017-10-12 IST"
```

whereas i was expecting the hours and mins to be included as well.

Also on trying to use

```
format(dmy_hms(df$sd), "%H:%M:%S")
```

I get that "All formats failed to parse. No formats found"

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: `strptime(df$sd, "%m/%d/%Y%H:%M")` works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the `lubridate` solution:

```
library(lubridate)

df <- data.frame(sd=c('10/12/2017 6:12','10/12/2017 6:14'),stringsAsFactors = F)

dmy_hm(df$sd)

#[1] "2017-12-10 06:12:00 UTC" "2017-12-10 06:14:00 UTC"
```